# dask.async.MemoryError on to_csv

Tags: python-2.7, dask

I am getting the following error message while trying to use dask to work with a relatively small subset of a larger data set. I first started getting this error message while running dask's implementation of GridSearchCV. But again when I tried to resolve it by writing the data frame to disk. The error message is below, followed by the code that I am trying to run.

> ### Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1578, in
>
> globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1015, in run
>
> pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
>
> File "C:/Users/Evan/Git/Data_Analysis_for_Exp/SEER Data/SEER_ML.py", line 73, in
>
> data.to_csv('data_frame_*.csv')
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 957, in to_csv
>
> return to_csv(self, filename, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\csv.py", line 445, in to_csv
>
> delayed(values).compute(get=get)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 95, in compute
>
> (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 202, in compute
>
> results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py", line 76, in get
>       **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\async.py", line 500, in get_async
>       raise(remote_exception(res, tb))
>
> dask.async.MemoryError:
>
> ### Traceback
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\async.py", line 266, in execute_task
>
> result = _execute_task(task, data)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\async.py", line 247, in _execute_task
>
> return func(*args2)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\csv.py", line 55, in pandas_read_text
>
> df = reader(bio, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
>
> return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 401, in _read
>
> data = parser.read()
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 957, in read
>
> df = DataFrame(col_dict, columns=columns, index=index)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 266, in **init**
>
> mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 402, in _init_dict
>
> return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5408, in _arrays_to_mgr
>
> return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4262, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
>
> blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4331, in form_blocks
>
> float_blocks = _multi_blockify(float_items)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4408, in _multi_blockify
>
> values, placement = _stack_arrays(list(tup_block), dtype)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4451, in _stack_arrays
>
> stacked = np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)

```
data = dataframe.read_csv("Data_Set_for_ML.csv", dtype={'colx': float, 'coly': float,'colz': float})
targets = data['target_col']
drop_these_too = ['target_col', "related_col1", "PID", "related_col2"]
drops = [key for key in list(list_of_features) if key not in 
list(selected_features) and key not in drop_these_too]
data = data.drop(drops, axis=1)
for col in list(data.columns):
    data[col].astype(float)
data.fillna(-9)
data.to_csv('data_frame_*.csv')
```

Comment: I notice you load all columns and then drop some before moving on - would it make sense to pass `usecols` to `read_csv` and never read them in? Also, can you specify all dtypes on load rather than doing `astype`? Finally, you may try decreasing `blocksize` in `read_csv`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have tried them, and still got a MemoryError. So, I am going to try again after ensuring that my 64bit Python interpreter is upto date with its dependencies etc. As an addendum: I checked my available RAM and found that I have approximately 4GB (a little over) of free RAM, and the size of the sample that I am working with is approximately 200MB so I am not sure what the issue is.